# Converting a Guid to Nullable Guid

Tags: c#, guid, nullable

Is this an idiomatic way to convert a `Guid` to a `Guid?`?

```
new Guid?(new Guid(myString));
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, this is:

```
Guid? foo = new Guid(myString);
```

There's an implicit conversion from `T` to `Nullable<T>` - you don't need to do anything special. Or if you're not in a situation where the implicit conversion will work (e.g. you're trying to call a method which has overloads for both the nullable and non-nullable types), you can cast it:

```
(Guid?) new Guid(myString)
```

Comment: Strange how Guid doesn't Parse or TryParse methods.

Comment: @David: They're coming in .NET 4, better late than never! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid_members%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: 5 years later: What? There was a time when Guids didn't have Parse or TryParse? How did you survive? I use it all the time!

Answer (score 4):

just cast it: (Guid?)(new Guid(myString))

there is also an implicit cast, so this would work fine as well:
Guid? g = new Guid(myString);